# Best way to fill a pothole in asphalt

Tags: driveway, patch, asphalt, gravel

What is the best way to fill a pothole in asphalt?

There are some huge potholes in an alley used by 5 homes that I would like to repair - meaning it gets a fair bit of traffic each day.

Would gravel be a sustainable filler into the holes?

Does it have to be more asphalt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cold patch [asphalt](http://m.homedepot.com/p/SAKRETE-50-lb-U-S-Cold-Patch-60450007/100672929) repair can be packed into holes and stands up well for standard car/truck use. If the hole is really deep you can pack crushed rock to fill the hole and save some $. I would not use pea gravel to fill the deeper holes as it never locks together like crushed rock. After filling and adding the patch material I like to run over it with my truck to pack it then if needed add a little more until the patch is even with the original level.

Comment: Better to overfill the hole set a strip of 3/4 plywood over the patch and than run it over a few times. Add more.  Leaving it higher as it will eventually become more compact as it is driven over.